# Implementing a panning window over an image?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-animate

I'm trying to implement an effect where there is a moving/animating window that pans over a background image such that you can only see a certain section of the image at a time.

Actually, the window itself should not move as it will be a div sitting somewhere on the page - but the effect should be the background moves behind it. The background however, should not take up any space on the DOM (i.e it should not affect any elements around it).

What is the best way to implement this? Should I just create a background image for the window div and then adjust the background-position? Can this be animated using jQuery?

```
____________________
|                   |
|   IMAGE           |
|   ___________     |
|   |  window |     |
|   |_________|     |
|___________________|
```

Comment: Sounds like the right plan to me.

Comment: I wonder if its possible to do this using css3 transitions.

Comment: You can do this with CSS3 animations (keyframes). screenmutt is pretty close, but you want to kill all the JavaScript and just create a looping animation that changes direction say in the keyframes to go from left to right.

Comment: @cirrus, that sounds exactly like what I want.  Can you elaborate a bit? Also, I am actually trying to animate the y position which I don' think should make a difference (but just thought I'd mention it in case it does).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPDATE: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/screenmutt/CBb83/5/) for CSS based animation.

Check out this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/screenmutt/CBb83/1/) make sure it's what you want.

HTML

```
<div class="window">
</div>
```

JS

```
var position = 135;
$('.window').click(function() {
    position += 20;
    $(this).css('background-position-x', position);
});
```

CSS

```
.window {
    background-image: url(image);
    display: block;
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    background-position: 135px -40px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. However, the JS fiddle doesn't appear to run.

Comment: I updated it just a second ago and posted a new link. [This one](http://jsfiddle.net/screenmutt/CBb83/1/) should run. Click on the image.

Comment: Thanks, this is more or less what I need, but I need to animate it (as opposed to onclick). Thinking about using jQuery animate or css3 transitions (possible?).

Comment: Updated it. Won't handle IE.

Comment: Thank you, I am going to continue playing around. If I don't get any better answers I will award this one.

Comment: And no comment on my epic picture :(... :p